# Designing proper REST URIs

Tags: http, url, rest, uri

I have a Java component which scans through a set of folders (input/processing/output) and returns the list of files in JSON format.

The REST URL for the same is:

```
GET http://<baseurl>/files/<foldername>
```

Now, I need to perform certain actions on each of the files, like validate, process, delete, etc. I'm not sure of the best way to design the REST URLs for these actions.
Since its a direct file manipulation, I don't have any unique identifier for the files, except their paths. So I'm not sure if the following is a good URL:

```
POST http://<baseurl>/file/validate?path=<filepath>
```

Edit: I would have ideally liked to use something like /file/fileId/validate. But the only unique id for files is its path, and I don't think I can use that as part of the URL itself.

And finally, I'm not sure which HTTP verb to use for such custom actions like validate.

Thanks in advance!

Regards,
Anand

Answer (score 2):

When you implement a route like http:///file/validate?path you encode the action in your resource that's not a desired effect when modelling a resource service.

You could do the following for **read operations**

GET http://api.example.com/files will return all files as URL reference such as

```
http://api.example.com/files/path/to/first
http://api.example.com/files/path/to/second
...
```

GET http://api.example.com/files/path/to/first will return validation results for the file (I'm using JSON for readability)

```
{
   name : first,
   valid : true
}
```

That was the simple read only part. Now to the **write operations**:

DELETE http://api.example.com/files/path/to/first will of course delete the file

Modelling the file processing is the hard part. But you could model that as top level  resource. So that:

POST http://api.example.com/FileOperation?operation=somethingweird will create a virtual file processing resource and execute the operation given by the URL parameter 'operation'. Modelling these file operations as resources gives you the possibility to perform the operations asynchronous and return a result that gives additional information about the process of the operation and so on.

You can take a look at [Amazon S3 REST API](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/2006-03-01/API/) for additional examples and inspiration on how to model resources. I can highly recommend to read [RESTful Web Services](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596529260.do)

Answer (score 1):

> Now, I need to perform certain actions on each of the files, like validate, process, delete, etc. I'm not sure of the best way to design the REST URLs for these actions. Since its a direct file manipulation, I don't have any unique identified for the files, except their paths. So I'm not sure if the following is a good URL: `POST http:///file/validate?path=`

It's not. `/file/validate` doesn't describe a resource, it describes an action. That means it is functional, not RESTful.

> Edit: I would have ideally liked to use something like `/file/fileId/validate`. But the only unique id for files is its path, and I don't think I can use that as part of the URL itself.

Oh yes you can! And you *should* do exactly that. Except for that final `validate` part; that is not a resource in any way, and so should not be part of the path. Instead, clients should POST a message to the file resource asking it to validate itself. Luckily, POST allows you to send a message to the file as well as receive one back; it's ideal for this sort of thing (unless there's an existing verb to use instead, whether in standard HTTP or one of the extensions such as WebDAV).

> And finally, I'm not sure which HTTP verb to use for such custom actions like validate.

POST, with the action to perform determined by the content of the message that was POSTed to the resource. Custom “do something non-standard” actions are always mapped to POST when they can't be mapped to GET, PUT or DELETE. (Alas, a clever POST is not hugely discoverable and so causes problems for the HATEOAS principle, but that's still better than violating basic REST principles.)

Answer (score 1):

REST requires a uniform interface, which in HTTP means limiting yourself to GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, etc.

One way you can check on each file's validity in a RESTful way is to think of the validity check not as an action to perform on the file, but as a resource in its own right:

```
GET /file/{file-id}/validity
```

This could return a simple True/False, or perhaps a list of the specific constraint violations.  The file-id could be a file name, an integer file number, a URL-encoded path, or perhaps an unencoded path like:

```
GET /file/bob/dir1/dir2/somefile/validity
```

Another approach would be to ask for a list of the invalid files:

```
GET /file/invalid
```

And still another would be to prevent invalid files from being added to your service in the first place, ie, when your service processes a PUT request with bad data:

```
PUT /file/{file-id}
```

it rejects it with an HTTP 400 (Bad Request).  The body of the 400 response could contain information on the specific error.

Update: To delete a file you would of course use the standard HTTP REST verb:

```
DELETE /file/{file-id}
```

To 'process' a file, does this create a new file (resource) from one that was uploaded?  For example Flickr creates several different image files from each one you upload, each with a different size.  In this case you could PUT an input file and then trigger the processing by GET-ing the corresponding output file:

```
PUT /file/input/{file-id}     
GET /file/output/{file-id}
```

If the processing isn't near-instantaneous, you could generate the output files asynchronously: every time a new input file is PUT into the web service, the web service starts up an asynchronous activity that eventually results in the output file being created.

Comment: According to Fielding your first statement is incorrect: "The REST style doesn't suggest that limiting the set of methods is a
desirable goal. [...] In particular, REST encourages the creation of new methods for obscure operations, specifically because we don't want to burden common methods with all of the logic of trying to figure out whether or not a particular operation fits the 99.9% case or one of the others that make up 0.1%." Source: http://xent.com/pipermail/fork/2001-August/003191.html That being said, I like your idea of validity as a resource in itself.

Comment: Also, status code 400 is more for the server itself, such as Apache, when it receives a malformed request -- not when the media type is malformed in the mind of the application. That would be status code 422 Unprocessable Entity.